# Calculate the tilt of a document from points?

Tags: math, geometry, geospatial

Imagine you have a PDF document.

On that document, you have identified two (x,y) coordinates that correspond to two (lat,lng) coordinates.

How do you calculate the tilt of the document - that is, what compass direction the top of the document is oriented to?

EDIT:

When I use the formula in the posted answer, it does not return the results I expect. For example:

```
The sample data look like y x (lat lng). 

The 1st test should be due north (0) and the 2nd should be due south (pi).

The first point is 0.000000 0.000000 (30.000000 60.000000) 
The second point is 0.000000 200.000000 (30.000000 120.000000) 
Theta is -0.000000

The first point is 0.000000 200.000000 (30.000000 60.000000) 
The second point is 0.000000 0.000000 (30.000000 120.000000) 
Theta is -0.000000
```

I am using:

```
float rho = atan(
                 (-y1 + y2) /
                 (-x1 + x2)
                );

float theta = atan(
                   ((lat2  - lat1 )*cos(rho) + (long1 - long2)*sin(rho))/
                   ((long1 - long2)*cos(rho) + (lat1  - lat2 )*sin(rho))
                  );
```

Comment: This is going to depend a lot on the scale and projection of the map.

Comment: Also, this is more of a math question rather than a programming one. See http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The area covered by the document is small enough that it's not warped very much by the projection.

Comment: Are you comfortable with vector algebra?

Comment: @Andrew I deleted my answer. Have to think a little more about it

Comment: Thanks, if you do have an answer, I will use it. I also asked a similar question on math.stackexchange.com and got an answer that I was able to use, for a related function. I think that I might be able to calculate the tilt of the plate using a piece of this method too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47244/how-do-i-calculate-where-to-plot-a-point-on-a-document-given-other-reference-poi

Answer (score 1):

1) If you have an angle of 0 -> this means it is pointing to the East! (or you must reverse your y's and x's in your equations).

2) You are dividing by zero in both cases. This is equal to infinite, which in most programming languages will cause a crash. If not, it will at least introduce some rounding errors. Try different values instead of 0 for both x coordinates...

You might want to consider:

```
float rho;
int denominator = -x1 + x2;
if(denominator == 0.0)
    rho = (-y1 + y2 > 0) ? pi/2.0 : -pi/2.0;
else
    rho = (-y1 + y2) / denominator;
```

Comment: Note that he doesn't actually want `pi/2` in every case where the denominator is zero. Sometimes he will want `-pi/2`.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Your answer is more complete, thanks for pointing it out to him

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Your algorithm has serious problems with the data you are giving it. Both of your example data points had `x1 = x2`, so when it was calculating `rho`, it had to find:

```
float rho = atan(
                 (-y1 + y2) /
                 0
                );
```

And dividing by zero is a problem. Why it just gave you garbage data instead of an error, I do not know.

Your algorithm should work fine as long as your two points aren't directly above one another. You could fix it a little bit by putting in a special case that if `x1 = x2 and y1 > y2`, then let `rho` be `pi/2`, and if `x1=x2 and y1 < y2`, then let `rho` be `-pi/2`. It looks like maybe you got your question answered on math.stackexchange already, but I'm sad that no one answered so I thought I'd post...

Comment: Programming languages commonly have a two argument arctangent function `atan2` specifically to avoid this problem.